# Find a sufficient statistic for $p$

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)$ be $\text{i.i.d.}$ $\text{Bin}(3,p)$ distributed and consider the estimator $\hat{p}(X) = \frac{X_1}{18} + \frac{X_2}{9} + \frac{X_3}{6}.$

First I had to show that $\hat{p}$ is unbiased, after some calculations I found: $E[\hat{p}] = p$

But the next question is that I have to show that this $\hat{p}$ is not sufficient and that I have to find a sufficient statistic for $p$.

Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you aware of the Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem for sufficient statistic?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that theorem. In this case, I do not know how to apply that theorem. I was able to solve similar question with other distributions. In this case, I have no clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiplying the three densities  you get

$$\binom{3}{x_1}\binom{3}{x_2}\binom{3}{x_3}p^{\sum x}(1-p)^{9-\sum x}=$$

$$=\underbrace{\binom{3}{x_1}\binom{3}{x_2}\binom{3}{x_3}}_{h(\mathbf{x})}\underbrace{(\frac{p}{1-p})^{\sum x}(1-p)^9}_{g[t(\mathbf{x}),p]}$$

Thus $T=\sum_i X_i$ is your sufficient estimator

In order to show that your $\hat{p}=\frac{x_1+2x_2+3x_3}{18}$ is not sufficient you can show that the conditional distribution $f_{X_1 X_2 X_3 | \hat{p}}$ is not independent from $p$ (a counterexample is enough)

COUNTEREXAMPLE

$$f(0,1,0|\hat{p}=\frac{2}{18})=...=1-p$$

that is not independent from $p$ and thus $\hat{p}=\frac{X_1+2X_2+3X_3}{18}$ is not sufficient for $p$

the denominator of the contitional probability is calculated considering that

$\hat{p}=\frac{2}{18}$ is achieved only in the following cases

1. $(0,1,0)$
2. $(2,0,0)$

Comment: Thankyou for sharing! I appreciate it and I will work on it.

Comment: Now I need to improve the above estimator with the sufficient statistic by using the Rao-Blackwell theorem. Is there any way you can give me a hint or example how to do that?